# Mathematical justification for the use of an energy shell in the microcanonical ensemble

Tags: measure-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, ergodic-theory, statistical-physics

I would like to understand an identity used in the deduction of the explicit formula for the probability distribution of the microcanonical ensemble in statistical mechanics.

Consider $\Lambda$ to be either a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ itself and $\Gamma = (\Lambda \times \mathbb{R}^{d})^{N}$, with $N \gg 1$. This is a topological space, so we can equip it with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{\Gamma}$. In the microcanonical ensemble, one restricts the analysis to an energy surface:
$$\Sigma_{E} := \{x \in \Gamma: H(x) = E\}$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system. In this case, the system is considered with a probability measure $\mu_{E}$ which is defined by the normalized Borel measure restricted to $\Sigma_{E}$. In the physics literature, this is written formally as:
$$d\mu_{E} = C\delta(H(x)-E)dx$$
where $C$ is the normalization constant and I am denoting $dx = d^{dN}qd^{dN}q$ the Borel measure.

Here is my question. To deduce that $d\mu_{E}$ has density $d\sigma_{E}/\|\nabla H\|$, it is usual to start with the following step. Consider the energy shell:
$$\Sigma_{[E,E+\delta]} := \{x \in \Gamma: E \le H(x) \le E+\delta\}$$
In this case, it is usually stated the following:
$$\int f(x)d\mu_{E}(x) = \lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{1}{\delta}\int_{\Sigma_{[E,E+\delta]}}f(x)dx. \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Question: why does (\ref{1}) holds true? Although I intuitively know this might be true, I can't prove it myself with rigorous mathematical reasoning. I have searched a lot of references looking for a justification, but I was only able to find intuitive/geometrical justifications.

Comment: One reference for the density result you mention is on page 45 in the notes: https://math.berkeley.edu/~rezakhan/math242_html/Symplectic.pdf,  "Lectures on Symplectic Geometry" by Fraydoun Rezakhanlou.